# mysql хранимая функция

Tags: mysql, sql

постигаю хранимые функции, но постоянно получаю ошибку, хотя вроде всё правильно.

```
USE ist;    
CREATE FUNCTION func() RETURNS INTEGER
BEGIN
SELECT count(*) INTO @count_all FROM users;
RETURN @count_all
END
```

ошибка `1064` возникает после `FROM` , если взять `users` в кавычки, то в ошибке будет это слово с кавычками, т.е. без кавычек он не увидит после `FROM` вообще ничего.
бд называется - ist , в ней одна таблица `users` c двумя INT полями - `id` и `tb` , что не так в моём запросе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример ниже.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS func;
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION func() RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE count INT;
    SELECT count(*) INTO count FROM table;
    RETURN count;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```